# Is it possible to restart Tomcat via web interface

Tags: web-server, tomcat

Is it possible to restart tomcat via some kind of administration tools. I would like to restart tomcat remotely via an administration tool that is accessible via web? If yes could you point me to some of them.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There's the tomcat manager.
This will allow  you to restart any installed webapp, as well as deploying and undeploying webapps.  It's pretty useful.  Located by default at `/manager/` on your tomcat installation.  You may need to set up user settings, or use the defaults from `tomcat-users.xml`.

If you actually want to physically restart the container, you'll want something at a lower level, perhaps webmin-like.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Tcat Server from MuleSoft to restart one or more Tomcat instances from the console. It is free for use in development. you can download it from: http://www.mulesoft.com/download-tcat-server-enterprise-tomcat

Hope this helps.

Disclaimer: I work for Mulesoft and is heavily involved with Tcat Server.